# Vaadin GridLayout removeComponent doesn't work

Tags: layout, vaadin

I have a View which extends GridLayout and has a 2x2 - Matrix.

Now I want to programmatically remove a component in one of the cells of the GridLayout with:

```
this.removeComponent( component );
```

But the component doesn't get removed at least the browser view doesn't get updated.

I also used:

```
this.removeComponent( col , row , component );
```

But the problem is still the same.

UPDATE: When I first do a component count :

```
int c = this.getComponentCount();
```

I get four.

After the removeComponent I get THREE - so it get's removed but the browser doesn't reflect this.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a sync problem, the client doesn't get notified from your server, so he doesn't know that this gridlayout has changed. 
So the client is not updating his view.

To fix this, you can use `@Push` annotation or add a "refresh" button.

Push ([see Doc](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/advanced.push.html)) allows you to call client actions from the server to update view. The problem you are actually having is that your element is not removed after a client action, so the client is not waiting for a content update, so nothing is updated.

Comment: Hi, I will try this out and will let you know if this works.